# Grabbing param value from #id=3333

Tags: php, javascript

I have this,

```
var stateObj = { foo: "foo" };
function change_my_url()
{
    if (window.history && window.history.pushState){
        history.pushState(stateObj, "page 2", "foo.html?id=3333");
    }else{
        location.hash = '#id=3333'
    }
}
```

In case window.history isnt supported, it will be #id=3333. Now if you load the page and it has a location.hash, it $.post request to file.php with it:

```
$.post('do_something.php', { hash: hash }, function(result) { $('#photos').html(result); });
```

in do_something im grabbing it with $_POST['hash'];. Now $_POST['hash'] will contain #id=3333. How can i divide in params and grab the value, '3333' ?

Comment: Are you just looking to turn the string '#id=3333' into '3333'?  If so, in PHP or in Javascript?

Comment: k, created an answer with two ways of doing that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to turn the string `#id=3333` into the string `3333`.

Split on '=':

```
$parts = explode('#', $inputString);
$value = $parts[1];
```

Remove the first four chars:

```
$value = substr($inputString, 3);
```